# Stop body scroll untill div is scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to make my page scroll normally and stop and fix on a certain point, then scroll div, and after div is completely scrolled continue scrolling body as usual.

I've tried to disable scrolling of the page and work with the wheel event, adding margin top to my content, but it doesn't seem to be a good solution.

Example of what i want https://aimbulance.com/ilayaregeneration

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not locking the scroll to the div, but masking the entire page and using `position: sticky` in order to achieve that.

**SOLUTION**

A possible solution is to make the div you want to be scrolled a container with `position: relative` that holds a masking element with `position: absolute` that covers the entire div and contains a mask that will be `position: sticky` with `top: 0`.

check out this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/scrolled-div-jqw7z

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked just like i needed!

Answer (score 0):

Use [overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html {
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    #section1 {
      height: 600px;
      background-color: pink;
    }

    #section2 {
      height: 600px;
      background-color: yellow;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      /* this is the usage */
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #inner {
      /* this height is larger than the parent */
      height: 1200px;
      width: 33%;
      background: radial-gradient(circle, black, white);
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #section3 {
      height: 600px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" id="section1">
  </div>

  <div class="main" id="section2">
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="main" id="section3">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: overflow-y is not the solution I need, because in this case you will have two independent scrolls, one for body and other for div, if hovered. I need one general scroll for body and div